# ActionCable Rails 5 on AWS: Error during WebSocket handshake 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, nginx, puma

Trying to deploy super simple rails 5 application to AWS using beanstalk.
Everything works fine except actioncable. Browser can't connect to the cable server.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://prod.3x52xijcqx.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

I found similar questions at stackoverflow but all of them were pointing to configure nginx using [this template](https://gist.github.com/KeithP/f8534c04d20c2b4e4b1d), however it didn't help me.

I customized nginx config using this script which I've put inside **.ebextensions**

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/websockets.conf":
    content: |
      upstream backend {
        server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
      }

      server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

      server {
        listen 80;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        server_name prod.3x52xijcqx.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com;

        # prevents 502 bad gateway error
        large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

          # prevents 502 bad gateway error
          proxy_buffers 8 32k;
          proxy_buffer_size 64k;

          proxy_pass http://backend;
          proxy_redirect off;

          location /assets {
            root /var/app/current/public;
          }

          # enables WS support
          location /cable {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
          }
        }
      }

container_commands:
  01_restart_nginx:
    command: "service nginx restart"
```

[Full app source is here](https://github.com/tenshilg/websocket_error_example)